# Loop in thread not exiting when flag is set

Tags: multithreading

I'm trying to exit out of a message loop in Java (JNA) by setting a flag, but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyClass() {

  private class MyInnerClass() implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

      MSG msg = new MSG();
      while(!quit && user32.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0) > 0) {

        user32.TranslateMessage(msg);
        user32.DispatchMessage(msg);
      }

      System.out.println("Exited message loop!");
    }

  } // MyInnerClass


  private volatile boolean quit;
  private final User32 user32;

  public MyClass() {

    quit = false;
    user32 = User32.INSTANCE;

    Thread myThread = new Thread(new MyInnerClass());
    myThread.start();
  }

  public void quit() {

    System.out.println("Entered quit()!");
    quit = true;
  }

} // MyClass
```

The method `quit()` is called in a callback that happens somewhere else in the code.

The message `Entered quit()!` shows on the screen, but the message `Exited message loop!` doesn't, and the thread keeps running.

Why is the message loop not stopping when I set `quit` to `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `GetMessage` never returns, so the loop condition `while (!quit && GetMessage() > 0)` is never tested after the first time.

In order to solve this, I refactored the code following the [example](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/w32keyhook/com/sun/jna/contrib/demo/KeyHook.java) provided on JNA's GitHub.

More specifically, I moved the `while (!quit)` to a separate thread from the `while (GetMessage() > 0)`, calling `System.exit(0)` when `while (!quit)` exits.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have to confuse some class instances or call function `quit()` as static member of class or you call function on another object that was not runned as thread. Also you need to check access to variable `quit` I am not so failiar with java but is it same variable which you have to set in one class and read from another?

Is it possible in java to capture variable? You have to create `new MyInnerClass()` and you need to set that variable `quit` which is memeber of `MyInnerClass` but not `MyClass`.

You create the instance of `MyInnerClass` and it now free to fly outside from `MyClass`. How instance of `MyInnerClass` will access to variable `quit` of `MyClass` when object of `MyClass` with varable `quit` will be released from memory and destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a variable of the outer class in a inner class. If you do so, Java will pass a copy of your outer class variable to your inner class. This is why you don't get a compiler error and the value doesn't change.

I found this information:

https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/accessing-outer-class-local-variables-from-inner-class-methods.html

Maybe it helps to declare the variable as static and access it by the name of your outer class.